# streamlit dataframe - live input values

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

Is it possible to add live values to the streamlit dataframe, then save it as a new dataframe and continue with dataframe manipulation ?

Let's say I upload on streamlit a dataframe like below:

| word | frequency | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 3 |  |
| green | 2 |  |
| house | 5 |  |

I want USER to input the values in "weight" column and save it to a new dataframe (where I later on perform some manipulation in the code). I am just wondering if such "live input" works in streamlit.

Comment: Not at the moment, but streamlit dev plans to support this. In the mean time, you can use [streamlit-aggrid](https://github.com/PablocFonseca/streamlit-aggrid) plus some data manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can currently use the [streamlit-aggrid](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-aggrid/) component to do this (guide on how to do this [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/make-dataframes-interactive-in-streamlit-c3d0c4f84ccb)). We're in the process of revamping `st.dataframe`, and the ability to edit the values is part of that (should be released in the next few months).